# Optaplanner - solverFactory creation slowed down a lot after upgrading to 8

Tags: optaplanner

I recently upgraded Optaplanner to 8, however I noticed that solverFactory creation slowed down by a lot, used to take around 200ms on my local machine, but now it's taking 4000+ms. This also happens on the server side too (almost 80% slower). In our use case, the solverFactory is frequently created (for different input) so this is really impacting the performance.

More specifically, this method call became a lot slower:

```java
SolverFactory<Solution_> solverFactory = SolverFactory.create(solverConfig);
```

I also tried

```
SolverFactory<Solution_> solverFactory = SolverFactory.createFromXmlResource(someXmlFile);
```

Both take around the same time and it's way slower than Optaplanner 7. (In 7 I used `SolverFactory.createFromXmlResource(someXmlFile)`)

Is there some way I could speed it up?

Some more information:
I'm using Optaplanner 8.22.0.Final with Score DRL, the way I set scoreDrl is just

```
solverConfig.getScoreDirectorFactoryConfig().setScoreDrlFileList(drlFileList);
```

We used to use kieBase to set scoreDrl in 7 btw.

The flame graph:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the flame graph. IMO it is obvious that most of the time is being spent in rule compilation and then ANC.

Comment: So is there some way to optimize this? Even after disabling ANC it's still almost 50% slower in solverFactory creation.

Comment: I do not see a way. You could use some scoring function that does not need to compile a rule base. (Easy, Incremental.)

Comment: For the record: with Constraint Streams and Quarkus, we could move all of this work to build-time, and then native compilation would have slashed the startup times to a very low number. But with score DRL, neither of those options are possible - which is part of the reason why we've deprecated score DRL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the flame graph, it appears that the culprit is Drools alpha network compilation. In constraint streams or DRL, ANC helps you get ~50 % increase in runtime performance, at the expense of one-time startup cost. (That cost happens at `SolverFactory` creation. The number reflects what we've seen in internal benchmarks, YMMV.)

ANC can be disabled in the solver config if you prefer, but I wouldn't. Another option would be to use Quarkus, which may move this work to build-time, allowing you to pay no compilation penalty at run-time; this only applies to CS though, score DRL does not support it.

If you're using programmatic solver configuration, [this](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/blob/8.22.1.Final/core/optaplanner-core-impl/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/core/config/score/director/ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.java#L286) is the method you need to call to disable ANC. Alternatively in XML solver config:

```
....
<scoreDirectorFactory>
    <scoreDrl>...</scoreDrl>
    <droolsAlphaNetworkCompilationEnabled>false</droolsAlphaNetworkCompilationEnabled>
    ...
</scoreDirectorFactory>
...
```

Comment: Thank you lukas, I editted my question with more information and yes I'm using DRL. Can you tell me how to disable ANC, so that I can see if it's worth it?

Comment: I updated my answer. Also FYI, DRL is newly deprecated: https://www.optaplanner.org/blog/2022/05/26/optaplanner-deprecates-score-drl.html